Why does Maven Surefire group dynamic JUnit5 tests as a single test?
I'm using Maven to run JUnit tests in my Java project, and I've noticed that when I use dynamic tests with @TestFactory, Maven seems to group them together as a single test, rather than treating each dynamic test as an individual test case, when at least one Test has failed.
This behavior is unexpected, as I would like the Tests to be static in number not changing depending on if a test fails.
Is there a configuration or workaround to ensure that Maven treats dynamic tests as distinct test cases?
I tried to get the dynamic Tests to work, the following is the minimal code to reproduce:
    @TestFactory
    Collection<DynamicTest> test_dynamic() {
        Collection<DynamicTest> tests = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String testName = "Test " + i;
            tests.add(dynamicTest(testName, () -> Assertions.assertTrue(false)));
            // [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

            // or [INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 when true

        }
        return tests;
    }

and run with:
╰─$ mvn clean test
i use the newest jupiter version, as well as the newest maven-surefire-plugin in my pom.xml file
